# Access python datetime that is returned from mysqldb query

Tags: python, datetime, mysql-python

When I execute the code below:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reportPref WHERE lastDate LIKE '2015-11-17%'")

records = cursor.fetchall()
print records
```

It returns (I shortened the result to just one row for brevity):

```
(22L, 4L, 88L, None, None, 11L, 3L, 1320L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1, datetime.date(2010, 3, 8), datetime.date(1970, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 5, 6, 32), 'test report', 0L, None, None, 1, 1, 0, None, None)
```

Index 14 is datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 5, 6, 32).  Is there some way I can call this datetime.datetime() that the database is returning directly USING datetime?  Because what I actually want to do is take just the time and convert it to seconds, but I can't figure out how to return just the time without doing stuff like splitting what's returned or trying to access the tuple entries for index 14 which isn't really what I want and is convoluted.  I want to call this datetime.datetime() value that's returned DIRECTLY using a datetime method call.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how can you return a scalar?  So instead of having to do records[0][14], records=date directly?  If so, you can change your query to select only that field

```
SELECT myDateCol FROM reportPref WHERE lastDate LIKE '2015-11-17%'
```

and then either write a sql class as an abstraction layer to MySQLdb where you can customize it to your use case or use sqlalchemy which already does that and has a scalar function.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar

Comment: No, I was wondering if, since mysqldb is returning index 14 as a datetime, if there was a way to simply query the database using the datetime module directly.  Or something like that.  In the end what I need to do is return just the time and convert it to seconds.

Comment: this makes no sense, can you add an example of what you want then.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I don't have a lot of python experience.  I guess I should edit my question.  I just need to take the time from index 14, which is tuple entries 3, 4 and 5, and convert it to seconds.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as follows:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reportPref WHERE lastDate LIKE '2015-11-17%'")

records = cursor.fetchall()

for record in records:
    rec = record[14]
    print rec.time()
```

Which returns output as follows:

```
18:06:24
17:06:01
00:06:05
18:06:24
17:06:06
18:06:24
    .
    .
    .
```

This is exactly what I needed!  Thanks for all of the support!